# Bug in beginner Binary search

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search, bluej

It shows the output when the Search value(SV) is present in the array. But not if it is not there. It keeps asking for input and keeps looping.

This is my first time attempting to make a code for binary search

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Binary_search {

    public static void main() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.length;

        //I used flag to end the loop 
        int Flag = 0;
        int mid = 0;
        int SV = input.nextInt();

        //here I enter values in the array
        for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++) {
            arr[x] = input.nextInt();
        }

        //here I start a loop for the search 
        while (Flag == 0) {
            mid = (start + end) / 2;

            if (mid == SV) {
                System.out.println("Number Found" + arr[mid]);
                Flag = Flag + 1;
            } else if (mid > SV) {
                end = mid - 1;
            } else if (mid < SV) {
                start = mid + 1;
            }

            //this was the second possibility if the number was not present   
            else if (start == end) {
                Flag = Flag + 1;
                System.out.println("Number not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the SV is present in the array it will show what position it is in, "Number Found" + arr[mid]. But if it is not there it is supposed to output, "Number not found", however, this does not happen and it keeps asking for input.

Comment: What input are you using? Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Your code is also missing how you setup that array. And note that variable names go camelCase in Java, and class names go UpperCase, no _ in them!

Comment: I remind you that in order for binary search to work, the array being searched must be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple way like this.
Please compare and check where you need to correct.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        int key = 3;
        binarySearchExample(arr, key);
    }

    public static void binarySearchExample(int arr[], int key) {
        int first = 0;
        int last = arr.length - 1;
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        while (first <= last) {
            if (arr[mid] < key) {
                first = mid + 1;
            } else if (arr[mid] == key) {
                System.out.println("Element is found at index: " + mid);
                break;
            } else {
                last = mid - 1;
            }
            mid = (first + last) / 2;
        }
        if (first > last) {
            System.out.println("Element is not found!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will use this code. Dumb of me trying not to use this feature when java gives it, I just a beginner :p. Again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like this to **input the numbers** from the user and store it in an  array and **search another inputted number** in the array with **binary search** and display its location.

```
import java.util.*;
class BinarySearch
{
   public static void main()
   {
      int i, num, item, array[], first, last, middle;
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter number of elements:");
      num = sc.nextInt();
      //array gets created by inputted space
      array = new int[num];
      System.out.println("Enter " + num + " integers");
      for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
          array[i] = sc.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter the number to be searched:");
      item = sc.nextInt();
      first = 0;
      last = num - 1;
      middle = (first + last)/2;

      //search starts
      while( first <= last )
      {
         if ( array[middle] < item )
           first = middle + 1;
         else if ( array[middle] == item )
         {
           //number found in
           System.out.println(item + " is found at location " + (middle + 1));
           break;
         }
         else
         {
             last = middle - 1;
         }
         middle = (first + last)/2;
      }
      if ( first > last )
          //number not found in array
          System.out.println(item + " is not found.\n");
   }
}
```